# How to sniff request packet on VPN server?

Tags: vpn, tcpdump, packet-sniffer

With some safe reasons, I need to sniff pptp cleint request packets,  then to get dst ip and src ip, for example `10.5.1.100 -> 218.100.211.100` , I want to know the correct rule in tcpdump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> tcpdump -i ethN port 1723 -vvv

Assuming that you literally just want to see the connection information and not run a packet cap.

Replacing ethN with the appropriate interface.